# Performance impact of empty LIKE in a prepared statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, prepared-statement, postgresql-performance

I have set a GiST [`pg_trgm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) index on the `name` column of the `files` table.

The simplified query of the prepared statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE name LIKE $1;
```

The `$1` param will be composed of `%` + user query + `%`. Since the input might also be an empty string this might result in `%%`.

Does an "empty" `LIKE` (`%%`) result in performance degradation? Should I build a new query in that case, or does it not matter?

Comment: Check the execution plan and you'll know

Comment: Would I ask if I knew how to use/read execution plans?

Comment: Then this is a good time to start learning that: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html and  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: @ErikAigner "Empty" like (`name LIKE '%%'`) will still filter out rows where `name is null`. If you want no filter at all - add `or length(user_query) = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres **9.2 or later** is generally smart enough to realize that the condition

```
WHERE name LIKE '%%'
```

is not selective and resorts to a sequential scan ignoring the GiST index - even with prepared statements. You *do* pay a small price for the useless condition, though.

In Postgres 9.1 or earlier I would build a separate query for the special case.

Compare the **Notes** section for the `PREPARE` statement in the manual for the versions [**9.1**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-prepare.html#AEN73409), [**9.2**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-prepare.html#AEN76106) and [**9.3**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-prepare.html#AEN78789).

#### Verify yourself

Prepare the statement and run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to test:

```
PREPARE plan1 (text) AS
SELECT  * FROM file
WHERE   name LIKE $1;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE plan1('%123%');

EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE plan1('%%');
```

[Plans are generally cached for the duration of the session.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-deallocate.html)

#### Alternative query

Regardless of the version you are running, if you always perform a full text search (wildcards left and right), this query should be faster for a prepared statement:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE name LIKE ('%' || $1 || '%');
```

And pass the pattern without added wildcards (`%`), of course. This way, Postgres knows to expect a pattern enclosed in wildcards at planning time.

->[**SQLfiddle demo.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/56d76/7)
Note the sequential scan for the empty LIKE and the performance difference between the two plans.
SQLfiddle varies a lot, depending on load etc. A single run may not be reliable. Better test in your environment and run each statement a couple of times to saturate cache and eliminate noise.

Comment: Did that already, but the `cost` still seemed marginally higher with `LIKE`.

Comment: So the cost seems to be `0.1` higher with `LIKE`, which I guess is negligible.

Comment: The first two queries are equal only if `name is not null`.

Comment: `name` is always not null in my case

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: You were right about the NULL case. I have completely rewritten the answer with more specific information by now.