# Why does a slight change in the search term slow down the query so much?

Tags: performance, postgresql, pattern-matching, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I have the following query in PostgreSQL (9.5.1):

```
select e.id, (select count(id) from imgitem ii where ii.tabid = e.id and ii.tab = 'esp') as imgs,
 e.ano, e.mes, e.dia, cast(cast(e.ano as varchar(4))||'-'||right('0'||cast(e.mes as varchar(2)),2)||'-'|| right('0'||cast(e.dia as varchar(2)),2) as varchar(10)) as data,
 pl.pltag, e.inpa, e.det, d.ano anodet, coalesce(p.abrev,'')||' ('||coalesce(p.prenome,'')||')' determinador, d.tax, coalesce(v.val,v.valf)||' '||vu.unit as altura,
 coalesce(v1.val,v1.valf)||' '||vu1.unit as DAP, d.fam, tf.nome família, d.gen, tg.nome gênero, d.sp, ts.nome espécie, d.inf, e.loc, l.nome localidade, e.lat, e.lon
from esp e
left join det d on e.det = d.id
left join tax tf on d.fam = tf.oldfam
left join tax tg on d.gen = tg.oldgen
left join tax ts on d.sp = ts.oldsp
left join tax ti on d.inf = ti.oldinf
left join loc l on e.loc = l.id
left join pess p on p.id = d.detby
left join var v on v.esp = e.id and v.key = 265
left join varunit vu on vu.id = v.unit
left join var v1 on v1.esp = e.id and v1.key = 264
left join varunit vu1 on vu1.id = v1.unit
left join pl on pl.id = e.pl
WHERE unaccent(TEXT(coalesce(p.abrev,'')||' ('||coalesce(p.prenome,'')||')')) ilike unaccent('%vicen%')
```

It takes 430ms to retrieve 1129 rows from a total of 9250 in `esp` table.

If I change the search term from `%vicen%` to `%vicent%` (adding a 't'), it takes 431ms to retrieve the same 1129 rows.

Ordering by the search column, ascending and descending, I see that all 1129 rows have exactly the same name in both cases.

Now the strange: if I change the search term from `%vicent%` to `%vicenti%` (adding an 'i'), now it takes unbelievable **24.4 seconds** to retrieve the same 1129 rows!

The searched term is always in the first `coalesce`, i.e. `coalesce(p.abrev,'')`. I expect the query to run slower or faster, depending on the size of the searched string, but not that much!! Anyone has any idea of what's going on?

Results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (would exceed the 30k character limit here):

For `%vicen%`: http://explain.depesz.com/s/2XF

For `%vicenti%`: http://explain.depesz.com/s/dEc6

Comment: It must be trying to use some other index at that point. Use EXPLAIN to show you execution plan for each.

Comment: Does this reproduce more than once?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plans for both queries using `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: @user1751825 When using EXPLAIN they all go very fast, but I'll try to understand the execution plan later. Thank you.

Comment: @TamasIonut Yes, many times. Really weird.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately, there's no room for both execution plans. I removed the beginning of the first one. Thank you!

Comment: You can upload them to http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: You *must* provide your version of Postgres for such a question. There have been major improvements to GIN indexes in Postgres 9.4 and 9.5. Better move your huge `EXPLAIN` output to http://explain.depesz.com/ and post a link. Why the odd predicate `WHERE unaccent(TEXT(coalesce(p.abrev,'')||' ('||coalesce(p.prenome,'')||')')) ilike unaccent('%vicen%')`? Do you have a matching index? Can you remove some of the (unrelated) `LEFT JOIN`s and still reproduce the effect? If so, please trim the clutter and provide an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also relevant: What do you get for `SHOW join_collapse_limit;`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter. No, I hadn't used any indexes yet. The odd predicate was just a repeat of the select field in the where clause, since we can't use the alias. I'll post the new version here, after I grasp all your suggested improvements. join_collapse_limit is 8.

Comment: What @ErwinBrandstetter says: probably the range table is beyond the collapse limit (12 or 14) and geqo kicks is. (workaround: use a CTE to squeeze out the trivial subquery, sucj as a lookup. Or: increase the limit)

Comment: BTW: you are not using any of the fields from **ti** `left join tax ti on d.inf = ti.oldinf`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why?

Fast query:

```
->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1378.60..2467.48 rows=15 width=79) (actual time=41.759..85.037 rows=1129 loops=1)
      ...
      Filter: (unaccent(((((COALESCE(p.abrev, ''::character varying))::text || ' ('::text) || (COALESCE(p.prenome, ''::character varying))::text) || ')'::text)) ~~* (...)
```

Slow query:

```
->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1378.60..2467.48 rows=1 width=79) (actual time=35.084..80.209 rows=1129 loops=1)
      ...
      Filter: (unaccent(((((COALESCE(p.abrev, ''::character varying))::text || ' ('::text) || (COALESCE(p.prenome, ''::character varying))::text) || ')'::text)) ~~* unacc (...)
```

Extending the search pattern by another character causes Postgres to assume yet fewer hits. (Typically, this is a reasonable estimate.) Postgres obviously does not have precise enough statistics (none, actually, see below) to expect the same number of hits that you really get.

This causes a switch to a different query plan, which is even less optimal for the ***actual*** number of hits `rows=1129`.

### Solution

One way to improve the situation is to create an **expression index** on the expression in the predicate. This makes Postgres gather statistics for the actual expression, which can help the query *even if the index itself is not used for the query*. Without the index, there are ***no statistics*** for the expression at all. And if done right the index can be used for the query, that's even much better. But there are ***multiple problems*** with your current expression:

<strike>`unaccent(TEXT(coalesce(p.abrev,'')||' ('||coalesce(p.prenome,'')||')')) ilike unaccent('%vicen%')`</strike>

Consider this updated query, based on **some assumptions** about your undisclosed table definitions:

```
SELECT e.id
     , (SELECT count(*) FROM imgitem
        WHERE tabid = e.id AND tab = 'esp') AS imgs -- count(*) is faster
     , e.ano, e.mes, e.dia
     , e.ano::text || to_char(e.mes2, 'FM"-"00')
                   || to_char(e.dia,  'FM"-"00') AS data    
     , pl.pltag, e.inpa, e.det, d.ano anodet
     , format('%s (%s)', p.abrev, p.prenome) AS determinador
     , d.tax
     , coalesce(v.val,v.valf)   || ' ' || vu.unit  AS altura
     , coalesce(v1.val,v1.valf) || ' ' || vu1.unit AS dap
     , d.fam, tf.nome família, d.gen, tg.nome AS gênero, d.sp
     , ts.nome AS espécie, d.inf, e.loc, l.nome localidade, e.lat, e.lon
FROM      pess    p                        -- reorder!
JOIN      det     d   ON d.detby   = p.id  -- INNER JOIN !
LEFT JOIN tax     tf  ON tf.oldfam = d.fam
LEFT JOIN tax     tg  ON tg.oldgen = d.gen
LEFT JOIN tax     ts  ON ts.oldsp  = d.sp
LEFT JOIN tax     ti  ON ti.oldinf = d.inf  -- unused, see @joop's comment
LEFT JOIN esp     e   ON e.det     = d.id
LEFT JOIN loc     l   ON l.id      = e.loc
LEFT JOIN var     v   ON v.esp     = e.id AND v.key  = 265
LEFT JOIN varunit vu  ON vu.id     = v.unit
LEFT JOIN var     v1  ON v1.esp    = e.id AND v1.key = 264
LEFT JOIN varunit vu1 ON vu1.id    = v1.unit
LEFT JOIN pl          ON pl.id     = e.pl
WHERE f_unaccent(p.abrev)   ILIKE f_unaccent('%' || 'vicenti' || '%') OR
      f_unaccent(p.prenome) ILIKE f_unaccent('%' || 'vicenti' || '%');
```

#### Major points

Why **`f_unaccent()`**? Because `unaccent()` can't be indexed. Read here:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

I used the function outlined there to allow the following (recommended!) multicolumn functional trigram GIN **index**:

```
CREATE INDEX pess_unaccent_nome_trgm_idx ON pess
USING gin (f_unaccent(pess) gin_trgm_ops, f_unaccent(prenome) gin_trgm_ops);
```

If you are not familiar with trigram indexes, read this first:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

And possibly:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Be sure to run the latest version of Postgres (9.5 at the time of writing). There have been substantial improvements to GIN indexes. And you'll be interested in improvements in pg_trgm 1.2, scheduled to be released with the upcoming Postgres 9.6:

- [Trigram search gets much slower as search string gets longer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111579/3684)

**Prepared statements** are a common way to execute queries with parameters (especially with text from user input). Postgres has to find a plan that works best for any given parameter. Add **wildcards as constants** to the to the search term like this:

```
f_unaccent(p.abrev) ILIKE f_unaccent('%' || 'vicenti' || '%')
```

(`'vicenti'` would be replaced with a parameter.) So Postgres knows we are dealing with a pattern that is neither anchored left nor right - which would allow different strategies. Related answer with more details:

- [Performance impact of empty LIKE in a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010932/performance-impact-of-empty-like-in-a-prepared-statement/19011108#19011108)

Or maybe re-plan the query for every search term (possibly using dynamic SQL in a function). But make sure planning time isn't eating any possible performance gain.

The **`WHERE` condition on columns in `pess` contradicts the <strike>`LEFT JOIN`</strike>**. Postgres is forced to convert that to an `INNER JOIN`. Unfortunately, the join comes late in the join tree. And since Postgres cannot reorder your joins (see below), that can become very expensive. Move the table to the ***first*** position in the `FROM` clause to eliminate rows early. Following `LEFT JOIN`s do not eliminate any rows by definition. But with that many tables it is important to move joins that might *multiply* rows to the end.

You are joining 13 tables, 12 of them with `LEFT JOIN` which leaves `12!` possible combinations - or `11! * 2!` if we take the one `LEFT JOIN` into account that's really an `INNER JOIN`. That's *too* many for Postgres to evaluate all possible permutations for the best query plan. Read about **`join_collapse_limit`**:

- [Sample Query to show Cardinality estimation error in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002263/sample-query-to-show-cardinality-estimation-error-in-postgresql/25002962#25002962)
- [SQL INNER JOIN over multiple tables equal to WHERE syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418581/sql-inner-join-over-multiple-tables-equal-to-where-syntax/27420244#27420244)

The default setting for `join_collapse_limit` is ***8***, which means that Postgres won't try to reorder tables in your `FROM` clause and the order of tables becomes ***relevant***.

One way to work around this would be to split the performance-critical part into a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) like [@joop commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343860/why-does-a-slight-change-in-the-search-term-slow-down-the-query-so-much?noredirect=1#comment60339150_36343860). Don't set `join_collapse_limit` much higher or times for query planning involving many joined tables will deteriorate.

About your **concatenated date** named `data`:

<strike>`cast(cast(e.ano as varchar(4))||'-'||right('0'||cast(e.mes as varchar(2)),2)||'-'|| right('0'||cast(e.dia as varchar(2)),2) as varchar(10)) as data`</strike>

*Assuming* you build from three numeric columns for year, month and day, which are defined `NOT NULL`, use this instead:

```
e.ano::text || to_char(e.mes2, 'FM"-"00')
            || to_char(e.dia,  'FM"-"00') AS data
```

About the `FM` template pattern modifier:

- [Check for integer in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277798/check-for-integer-in-string-array/34288654#34288654)

But really, you should store the date as data type [`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) to begin with.

Also simplified:

```
format('%s (%s)', p.abrev, p.prenome) AS determinador
```

Won't make the query faster, but it's much cleaner. See [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

First things last, all the usual advice for **performance optimization** applies:

- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/keep-postgresql-from-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan/8229000#8229000)

If you get all of this right, you should see much faster queries for *all* patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer, Erwin! I'll answer each point as I go through. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Why f_unaccent()? Because in Brazil accents are very common in people's names: João, José, Luís, Mário... I'm looking at your strategy.

Comment: @Rodrigo: I think you misunderstood concerning `f_unaccent()`. `unaccent()` is obviously useful. I am just explaining *why* I use my custom function `f_unaccent()` instead of `unaccent()` out of the box. [Follow the link above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216) for details.

Comment: Really, I misunderstood it. Your single answer gave me material for study for several days hehehe thanks again!

Comment: The date is spread into three columns because sometimes we only have the year, or year+month, of a given record. There are some alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599997/iso-8601-in-postgres-how-to-insert-only-year-in-type-date-incomplete-date-tim -- but I'm not sure yet which is the best.

Comment: What's the point in using f_unaccent('%' || 'vicenti' || '%') instead of f_unaccent('%vicenti%')?

Comment: @Rodrigo: I added a bit to address concatenated wildcards. About date storage: ask a new question if you don't find a solution (this answer is getting big already). You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: For a long time I hadn't work on that. Now I remembered an important thing: this query is created on run-time. The WHERE in the end depends on which column the user has filtered (may involve many columns). So I think the order change (pess instead of esp) may not be practical. Still studying the query, though.

Answer (score 2):

A way to reduce the size of the range table is to squeeze out a trivial part of the query into a CTE, such AS:

```
WITH zzz AS (
        SELECT l.id, l.nome
        , coalesce(v.val,v.valf)||' '||vu.unit as altura
        , coalesce(v1.val,v1.valf)||' '||vu1.unit as DAP
        FROM loc l 
         left join var v on v.esp = l.id and v.key = 265
         left join varunit vu on vu.id = v.unit
         left join var v1 on v1.esp = l.id and v1.key = 264
         left join varunit vu1 on vu1.id = v1.unit
        )
select e.id, (select count(id) from imgitem ii
                where ii.tabid = e.id and ii.tab = 'esp'
                ) as imgs
        , e.ano, e.mes, e.dia
        , cast(cast(e.ano as varchar(4))||'-'||right('0'||cast(e.mes as varchar(2)),2)||'-'|| right('0'||cast(e.dia as varchar(2)),2) as varchar(10)) as data
        , pl.pltag, e.inpa, e.det, d.ano anodet
        , coalesce(p.abrev,'')||' ('||coalesce(p.prenome,'')||')' determinador
        , d.tax

        , zzz.altura as altura
        , zzz.DAP as DAP

        , d.fam, tf.nome família
        , d.gen, tg.nome gênero
        , d.sp , ts.nome espécie
        , d.inf, e.loc
        , zzz.nome AS localidade
        , e.lat, e.lon
from esp e
left join det d on e.det = d.id         -- these could possibly be
left join pess p on p.id = d.detby      -- plain joins
        -- 
left join tax tf on d.fam = tf.oldfam
left join tax tg on d.gen = tg.oldgen
left join tax ts on d.sp = ts.oldsp
 -- ### commented out, since it is never referred
 -- ### left join tax ti on d.inf = ti.oldinf
left join pl on pl.id = e.pl
left JOIN zzz ON zzz.id = e.loc
        -- 
WHERE unaccent(TEXT(coalesce(p.abrev,'')||' ('||coalesce(p.prenome,'')||')')) ilike unaccent('%vicen%')
        ;
```

[untested, since I don't have the table definitions]